Sublinear function $f$ with $f(x)+f(-x)=0$ for some $x \neq 0$ is linear.
A sublinear function $f$ has the following properties:

$f(x+y) \leq f(x) + f(y)\;\; \forall x,y \in \mathbb R^d$
for any $t > 0, x \in\mathbb R^d, f(tx) = tf(x)$

Now let $f(x_0) + f(-x_0) = 0$ at some point $x_0 \neq 0$, I want to prove that $f$ is actually linear.
I have proved $f(0)=0$ by simply let $x = y = 0$ and $x = x_0, y= -x_0$, but I don't know how to proceed. Could someone help me?

$(x_1,x_2) \mapsto \max(0, x_1)$.

This will not hold as it is:

$f$ sublinear and $f(x_0)+f(-x_0)=0$ at some point $x_0 \neq 0$ means that $f$ is linear.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x) = |x_1|$. This function satisfies that
$f(x+y) \leq f(x) + f(y) \;\forall x,y \in \mathbb R^2$
for any $t > 0, x \in\mathbb R^2, f(tx) = tf(x)$.
And for $x_0 = [0;1]$ we have $f(x_0)+f(-x_0)=0,$ but $f$ is not linear.

+1. Do you know if the statement holds if we change "$t>0$" to "$t\in\mathbb{R}$?"

Then it will. For any scalars $\alpha, \beta$, start with $f(\alpha x + \beta y)$ and apply the inequality twice and the homogeneity property a few times. You should get $f(\alpha x + \beta y)= \alpha f(x)+\beta f(y)$
